# display menu and multilevel submenu

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I need to display a menu list and multilevel submenu list, ex:

menu1
--menu2
----menu3
--menu4
menu5
--menu6

here are my code:

model:

```
class Menu(models.Model):
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    parent_id = models.ForeignKey(u'self', null=True, blank=True, related_name=u'parent_menu')
```

view:

```
menu = {}
map(lambda c: menu.setdefault(c.parent_id, []).append(c), \
            Menu.objects.filter(status=True).select_related('parent_menu'))
context['menu'] = menu
return context
```

template:

```
{% for mymenu, mysubmenu in menu.items %}
  {{ category.name }}
  {% for mysubmenu in mysubmenu %}
    {{ mysubmenu }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

the actual problem is, I don´t get the correct list of more than one level. now display something like:

menu1
--menu2
menu2
--menu3
--menu4
menu5
--menu6